# If $a \equiv b \mod m$ and $0 \leq a$ and $b < m$, $a=b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I was reading Hodel's otherwise excellent *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic* and, in the appendix on number theory, specifically on the section on congruences, he seems to make a slip. Let $a, b, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m > 0$. He claims that:

> If $a \equiv b \mod m$ and $0 \leq a$ and $b < m$, $a=b$

But that seems clearly mistaken, for take $a = 22$, $b= 4$ and $m = 9$. In that case, clearly $22 \equiv 4 \mod 9$, $0 \leq 22$, and $4 < 9$, but equally clearly $22 \not = 4$. Am I missing something? If not, and this is indeed a (trivial) counter-example to Hodel's claim, is there any other similar property about congruences that he could be referring to?

Comment: Perhaps he means that if "$a$ and $b$" are between $0$ and $m$...

Comment: It says $a$ and $b$ less than $m$. But $22$ is not less than $9$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I thought those were two separate conditions, not the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just unfortunate notation. The statement should be read
$$
0\leq \text {($a $ and $b $)}<m,
$$
and not
$$
0\leq a, \text { and } b <m.
$$

Comment: Yes, yes, thank you. Now the result follows easily from the fact that, if $a | b$ and $b > 0$, then $a \leq b$. Hah, from an incorrect statement to an easy result... thank God for this site!